# Confusion with forking and global variables

Tags: c, multithreading, fork

Why does printing on line 22 result in 1 instead of 3? `count` is a global variable and it was already modified in handlerA, so why didn't it retain its value on line 21 and 22?

```
1    pid_t pid;
2    int count = 0;
3    
4    void handlerA(int sig) {
5        count += 2
6        printf("count = %d\n", count);
7        fflush(stdout);
8        kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
9    }
10
11   void handlerB(int sig) {
12       count += 3;
13       printf("count = %d\n", count);
14       fflush(stdout);
15       exit(0);
16   } 
17
18  int main() {
19     signal(SIGUSR1, handlerA);    
20     if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {
21          count++;
22          printf("count = %d\n", count);
23          fflush(stdout);
24          signal(SIGUSR1, handlerB);
25          kill(getpid(), SIGUSR1);
26          while (1) {};
27     }
28     else {
29          wait();
30          count += 4;
31          printf("count = %d\n", count);
32          fflush(stdout);
33     }
34     return 0; 
35   }
```

Comment: “already modified” how?

Comment: as in incremented by 2 already

Comment: Perhaps `man 2 fork` "*The child process and the parent process run in separate memory spaces.*" In other words, "*The child process is an exact duplicate of the parent process...*", but is created in a separate memory space. So it inherits the value of the global at the time of `fork`, but it is not updated by any other process thereafter.

Comment: So you think `handlerA` was called at that point? How?

Comment: @Superman Oh so since it's asynchronous does that mean count could be 0 or 2?

Comment: You can't safely call any non-async-signal-safe function from a signal hander.  Calling `printf()` and `fflush()` from a signal handler is undefined behavior.  See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the confusion is stemming from [`signal()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/signal): it's a function that is simply setting the `handlerA` to handle `SIGUSR1`.

The signal is not being invoked nor are any of the handlers triggered in any way by the time line 22 is reached. So the program calls `fork()` and `count` increments from 0 to 1, like expected.

You would see the behavior you're expecting if you also `kill(pid, SIGUSR1);` in `main` somewhere before the fork.

Don't re-raise the signal inside of that signal's respective handler.